# How to get HTTP-Referer via JS | Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-referer

Is it possible to get the `http-referer` of visitors via pure JS or with JQuery?

Comment: [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer)...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes. Just use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer).

Comment: A direct link doesn't have a referer anyways.

Comment: you are faster, damn :D

Comment: @Scimonster Not true about "direct link doesn't have referer". New Rules here http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2 Must be `about:blank`