# Landing Page, preventig access by direct url or to the user coming outside the facebook ads

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to redirect all the users they are not being redirected from Facebook Ad to a regular static page instead of an Landing Page. The Landing Page should be visible just to the users they access it through a Facebook ad. If they are trying to access this landing page with direct URL or coming from different sources than they should be redirected to a different static page. Can be done just with javascript? and without modifying the .htaccess?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the `referer` HTTP header? It should contain the domain which referred you to the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read out `document.referrer` in js and act accordingly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

This should contain the page the user is comming from!

Also see here: [How to get HTTP-Referer via JS | Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716858/how-to-get-http-referer-via-js-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You may also take a look into the `Referer` HTTP Header to perform the redirection on the server side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: Ok perfect, i took a look to the Referer and it is exactly wahat i was looking for. Thank you all and Regards

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to check where the request is coming from is: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. But According to the official PHP documentation:
 **"This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted".**